# Is it possible to run a fstab present in non-root partition on FreeBSD bootup?

Tags: freebsd, fstab

I have a FreeBSD 10.2 based x86_64 machine with read-only root. For security reason I cannot mount '/' as r/w or remount it as r/w post bootup.

Sometimes I have to change file system of one of partition from UFS to ext2. To boot cleanly after FS change fstab need to be modified which due to above constraints I am not able to do now.

To get around RO root constraints I'm thinking of replacing '/etc/fstab' with a symbolic link from '/etc/fstab' to actual fstab in '/efi/fstab where '/efi' is a  non-root partition with r/w access. Problem is how to make OS to run /'efi/fstab' on bootup time as 'efi' is mounted by fstab itself.

This may be little ugly fix but with given constraints this is what have in mind as of now. Open for better ideas/suggestions.

Mount command give an option to specify an alternative fstab file. Not sure if alternative path mention in description here can be on non-root partition and if yes, how to do that. Anyone have tried this option?

> -T, --fstab path
>                 Specifies an alternative fstab file.  If path is a directory
>                 then the files in the directory are sorted by strverscmp(3);
>                 files that start with "." or without an .fstab extension are
>                 ignored.  The option can be specified more than once.  This
>                 option is mostly designed for initramfs or chroot scripts
>                 where additional configuration is specified beyond standard
>                 system configuration.

Comment: You only have to modify /etc/fstab once though, when you set up the system, not every time you boot ... How is this different to setting up any other config file on your root system (e.g. init scripts)?

Comment: You cannot link `/etc/fstab` to an unmounted filesystem.

Comment: @Time4Tea Box Sorry I didn't get your point.

Comment: My point is that, at some point, the root filesystem had to be mounted with write access, in order for the system to be installed and set up in the first place. Why didn't you configure /etc/fstab at that stage and why couldn't it be done again?

Comment: @RichardSmith Is it possible to  mount partition that have 'fstab' to explicitly during boot-up so that os can access it and run fstab present there? In that case I will need  require symbolic link.  For example a partition 'efi'  will be msdos always . I can put fstab there. But how to make OS pick this fstab.

Comment: I think you're going to have all sorts of problems down the road, if your system doesn't have the ability for someone to go in with write access to the root partition somehow. How do you intend to maintain it?

Comment: @Time4Tea It's a legacy product. We don't expect client to do much in root partition. Arrangement seems working so far. Sorry but no good answer :)

Comment: It sounds like what you are trying to do is build an unmaintainable Linux installation, which strikes me as a very bad idea.